# Using foldr and a lambda expression as its first argument

Tags: list, haskell, lambda

I'm trying to figure out how to use lambda expressions and I saw that they're commonly used in functions such as foldl or foldr.

I'm wondering why the following code doesn't work:

```
ExMin = foldr (\x y -> x < y) 5 [1,2,3,4]
```

I want this function to give me the minimum number in the list, however it gives error.
I'm thinking that the reason it errors is because x < y returns a boolean, and what I'm expecting from it is an integer.

Any ideas on how I can make it return the number correctly?

Comment: `foldr (\x y -> x < y) 5 [1,2,3,4]` would evaluate to `1 < (2 < (3 < (4 < 5))))` which is ill-typed, since it's trying to compare numbers with booleans. The lambda must return something that can be fed back to the same lambda as second argument, i.e. it has to have a type of the form `a -> b -> b`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm wondering why the following code doesn't work:
>
> ```
> ExMin = foldr (\x y -> x < y) 5 [1,2,3,4]
> ```

Because a foldr function takes a folding function with type `a -> b -> b` where `b` is the type of the "accumulator", a value that is passed right-to-left and each time is taken as input to the fold function and another element. Eventual `foldr` returns the final value for the accumulator.

> Any ideas on how I can make it return the number correctly?

Yes, you can use the [**`min :: Ord a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:min) function. This will each time return the minimum of the accumulator and an element:

```
ExMin = foldr min 5 [1,2,3,4]
```

As [@amalloy says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64718165/using-foldr-and-a-lambda-expression-as-its-first-argument/64718192?noredirect=1#comment114434366_64718192) you can not use variables that start with an **U**ppercase, this should be a lowercase:

```
exMin = foldr min 5 [1,2,3,4]
```